# Как корректно поставить jupyter с помощью pipenv?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Друзья, нужна помощь! Для виртуального окружения использую pipenv . Устанавливаю spacy.

```
pipenv install spacy
pipenv install jupyter
```

Все ставится, ноутбук запускается, вот только

```
import spacy
```

выдает ошибку. Пишет, что библиотека не установлена.

При этом, если в консоли набрать:

```
python
import spacy
```

все находится и работает.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно зарегистрировать ваше виртуальное окружение как ядро для Jupyter. Как это делаю я (используя простой venv, но думаю и вам подойдет): активируем созданное виртуальное окружение и устанавливаем `ipykernel`:

```
pip install ipykernel
```

Далее выполняем:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=pandas_venv
```

В списке доступных ядер Jupyter появится ядро с именем `pandas_venv`. Возможно придется перезапустить Jupyter.

**Edit**: Увидел, что Jupyter у вас уже установлен в виртуальное окружение. Тогда попробуйте просто выполнить вторую команду. Я запускаю Jupyter lab глобально, а для окружений устанавливаю только `ipykernel`, который хоть и тянет за собой какие-то зависимости, но меньше, чем при установке всего пакета `jupyter`.